# Create a column in Spark df based on several values in different column

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark df that roughly looks like this:

```
company ID  quarter     metric
  12       31-12-2019    54.3     
  12       30-09-2019    48.2
  12       30-06-2019    32.3
  12       30-03-2019    54.3
  23       31-12-2018    54.3
  23       30-09-2018    48.2
  23       30-06-2018    32.3
  23       30-03-2018    54.3
  45       31-12-2021    54.3
  45       30-09-2021    48.2
  45       30-06-2021    32.3
  45       30-03-2021    54.3
  45       31-12-2021    54.3
  45       30-09-2020    48.2
  45       30-06-2020    32.3
  45       30-03-2020    54.3
  ..           ..         ..
```

For each quarter row for each company ID I need to compute an annual value from the following quarters i.e for company ID = 45 and quarter = 30-06-2020 annual value would be equal to:

```
30-03-2021    54.3
31-12-2020    54.3
30-09-2020    48.2
30-06-2020    32.3
            --------
              189,1
```

Result:

```
   company ID  quarter     metric   annual
      12       31-12-2019    54.3     
      12       30-09-2019    48.2
      12       30-06-2019    32.3
      12       30-03-2019    54.3
      23       31-12-2018    54.3
      23       30-09-2018    48.2
      23       30-06-2018    32.3
      23       30-03-2018    54.3
      45       31-12-2021    54.3
      45       30-09-2021    48.2
      45       30-06-2021    32.3
      45       30-03-2021    54.3
      45       31-12-2021    54.3
      45       30-09-2020    48.2
      45       30-06-2020    32.3   **189,1**
      45       30-03-2020    54.3
      ..           ..         ..
```

In pandas I would probably groupby by entity ID and then would try to compute a column based on indices or something like that. What would be the most effective way to do it in Spark/Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date can be converted to days since 1970, and Window function with range 366 days back with "sum" can be used, on Scala:

```
val df = Seq(
  (12, "31-12-2019", 54.3),
  (12, "30-09-2019", 48.2),
  (12, "30-06-2019", 32.3),
  (12, "30-03-2019", 54.3),
  (23, "31-12-2018", 54.3),
  (23, "30-09-2018", 48.2),
  (23, "30-06-2018", 32.3),
  (23, "30-03-2018", 54.3),
  (45, "31-12-2021", 54.3),
  (45, "30-09-2021", 48.2),
  (45, "30-06-2021", 32.3),
  (45, "30-03-2021", 54.3),
  (45, "31-12-2021", 54.3),
  (45, "30-09-2020", 48.2),
  (45, "30-06-2020", 32.3),
  (45, "30-03-2020", 54.3),
)
  .toDF("company ID", "quarter", "metric")

val companyIdWindow = Window.partitionBy("company ID").rangeBetween(-366, Window.currentRow).orderBy("days")

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
val secondsInDay = TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1)
df
  .withColumn("days", unix_timestamp($"quarter", "dd-MM-yyyy") / secondsInDay)
  .withColumn("annual", sum("metric").over(companyIdWindow))
  .drop("days")
```

Result:

```
+----------+----------+------+------------------+
|company ID|quarter   |metric|annual            |
+----------+----------+------+------------------+
|23        |30-03-2018|54.3  |54.3              |
|23        |30-06-2018|32.3  |86.6              |
|23        |30-09-2018|48.2  |134.8             |
|23        |31-12-2018|54.3  |189.10000000000002|
|45        |30-03-2020|54.3  |54.3              |
|45        |30-06-2020|32.3  |86.6              |
|45        |30-09-2020|48.2  |134.8             |
|45        |30-03-2021|54.3  |189.10000000000002|
|45        |30-06-2021|32.3  |167.10000000000002|
|45        |30-09-2021|48.2  |183.0             |
|45        |31-12-2021|54.3  |243.40000000000003|
|45        |31-12-2021|54.3  |243.40000000000003|
|12        |30-03-2019|54.3  |54.3              |
|12        |30-06-2019|32.3  |86.6              |
|12        |30-09-2019|48.2  |134.8             |
|12        |31-12-2019|54.3  |189.10000000000002|
+----------+----------+------+------------------+
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but it kind of blew my mind. This might be pushing limits but is it possible you are able to show how this code would look in python? I did not expect the answer to be in Scala, thought python was the default language - clearly not the case.

Comment: I am not familiar with Python, sorry.